# SVN to TFS 2010 Free?

Tags: svn

I am trying to find a tool to migrate SVN to TFS 2010. The tools I have found, or have been suggested on this site are fairly expensive (like timely migration) or do not seem to work with 2010 . Does anyone know of a cheaper option or some manual scripting process to accomplish this ?

Comment: Do you actually require history to be migrated to TFS? Consider checking in the latest version, and leave history in Subversion.

Comment: We have considered that approach and it looks like we may end up with that one, this is the third change in source control for my team, and we did that for the first two so it would be good to avoid that (PVCS --> VSS --SVN --> TFS)

Comment: wow uber sc journey bro. I'm glad u ended on tfs 2010

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
http://svn2tfs.codeplex.com/
quite handy, you might have to worry about renamed file in svn specially when renames is just case change.
/G